# Random NSNumber from array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to make an IBAction pick a random float from an `NSMutableArray` (10.00, 2.56, 4.25, 1.95).

Here's what I tried:

In the viewDidLoad:

```
NSMutableArray *numberPicker = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.00],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.56],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.25],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.95],
                                  nil];
```

In the IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender{
result = [numberPicker objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [numberPicker count])];
```

Obviously this isn't working, i get an error "Assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'id'".
Any ideas how to get one of the numbers into "result"?

Comment: Please use more sense full tagging. most likely nobody has [nsnumber] in the list of interesting tags. As `NSNumber` is part of Cocoa, tag it [cocoa], as the language is Objective-C, also use [objective-c].

Answer (score 3):

You just change one line to:

```
result = [[numberPicker objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [numberPicker count])] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method `randomElement` in a category on NSArray

```
#import "NSArray+RandomUtils.h"

@implementation NSArray (RandomUtils)


-(id)randomElement
{
    if ([self count] < 1) return nil;
    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [self count];
    return [self objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
}
@end
```

or just use the one, [I wrote.](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/arraytools/tree/master/arraytools)

You will use it like this:

- `#import "NSArray+RandomUtils.h"`
- Use a property numberPicker `@property (retain) NSArray *numberPicker`
- `viewDidLoad:`

  ```
  self.numberPicker = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.00],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.56],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.25],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.95],
                            nil];
  ```
- in your `buttonPressed:` use

  ```
  result = [(NSNumber *)[self.numberPicker randomElement] floatValue];
  ```